# Is There Anything Wrong With Parameters & Arguments Having The Same Name

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, arguments

I see so often that the parameters & arguments for functions are differently named.

I wonder whats wrong with the following:

```
// aFunc takes two variables 'first' & 'second'
var aFunc = function( first, second ){
 ...
}

var first = "first",
    second = "second";

aFunc( first, second );
```

Is there a reason, both the arguments & the parameters being passed to the function should not be the same name?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, just a matter of preference.

Comment: It depends on the context and preference. It's often best to go with that's clearest to a reader.

Comment: The whole point of functions is that you can call them with different arguments, so although it can occasionally happen that the variables you pass in have the same names as the parameters, it's usually not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong technically. In most situation your parameter and variable name will be renamed to something short ( a, b, c) by the compiler or interpreter. Pay attention to scoping.

The takeaway idea is trying to convey meaning and information thought your naming.

Sometimes it will makes senses or convey information to differentiate the parameter name in the declaration.

For instance:

```
// aFunc takes 3 variables, the name should speak for itself.
var aFunc = function( maximum, minimum, average ){
 ...
}

aFunc( localMinimum, localMaximum, localAverage );
aFunc( weekMin, weekMax, weekAverage );
aFunc( allTimeMin, allTimeMax, allTimeAverage );
```

In that exemple, it's clear what kind of max, min and average value I'm passing to the aFunc function.